# Cannot get Bootstrap TypeAhead to work inside key up event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

If i run typeahead alone inside doc ready it runs fine:

```
$('#near').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/ajaxcall.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'query=' + query,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                process(data);   
            }
        });
    },

    minLength:3,
    items:100
    });
```

if i wrap it inside a keyup event it does not work:

```
$('#near').keyup(function(){

console.log('keyup value is ' + $('#near').val());

$('#near').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/ajaxcall.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'query=' + query,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                process(data);   
            }
        });
    },

    minLength:3,
    items:100
    });
});
```

My question is why does it stop working inside the event handler even though i am seeing that the event triggers and updates the value in console? Also is there a way to get it working in the context of the keyup event. eventually i want to check to see if the value is a number or string on key up and call a different typeahead ajax call depending on the answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To strictly answer your question: It won't work that way. When you call .typeahead() on your #near field, you are initializing Typeahead.  That is, you're making a call to the typeahead library, which then attaches all kinds of other listeners and classes and DOM elements hanging off of #near.  If you put this call in a keyup event, all this setup is getting run with every press.  You'll need to move the typeahead() call outside of the keyup listener- you only want it to run once.

But that's not to say you can't make different AJAX calls depending on the input. If you want to vary the source that typeahead uses at runtime, you should be able to point it to a function expression that returns a couple different functions.  Which one it returns could depend on a value that gets altered within your keyup listener.  That might look something like this:

```
// This is declared outside of of the keyup listener function and the 
// sourceSwitcher, so that it is available to both. We're assuming string, 
// but we'll check on each keyup.
var nearIsInteger = false;

// This matches the user input against a crude regex- if the input consists
// of nothing but digits, it sets nearIsInteger to true.
$('#near').keyup(function(){
    var userInput = $(this).val();
    if (/^\d+$/.test(userInput)) {
        nearIsInteger = true;
    } else {
        nearIsInteger = false;
    }
});

// This is a function expression.  Notice that it is not a simple declaration; 
// the entire function is declared within a variable, which can be called at
// runtime when it is referenced (by appending empty parentheses). Of course, 
// you'll need to make it return function expressions of your own- the return 
// values here are just placeholder strings.
var sourceSwitcher = function(){
    if (nearIsInteger) {
        return "source function (ajax call) for integer input";
    } else {
        return "different source function for other strings";
    }
};


// Here is your current typeahead initialization. You should now be able to set the remote source to call whichever
// function is being returned by the source switcher. Instead of the function you are currently specifying for source,
// call sourceSwitcher(), which should now return the appropriate one of your functions.

$('#near').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/ajaxcall.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'query=' + query,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                process(data);   
            }
        });
    },
    minLength:3,
    items:100
});
```

I'm not sure whether typeahead reloads the initial dataset more than once, though, so you may need to do some fancier configuration to get this to work- specifying a remote source that gets called repeatedly at runtime.  Good luck!

Comment: Im not quite understanding what you mean by varying the source based on function expression. Can you maybe give a small example of how that would look?